# Why does this ArrayList 'add' operation not add the new element?

Tags: java, arraylist

When I run this code I expect an ArrayList with one element, the String "Hi", to be added to the ArrayList at the 0th index. When I print the element at the 0th index I don't get "Hi", rather I get **true**. I don't know how to interpret that result.

```
package dataTypes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataTypes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList myUnsafeArrayList =  new ArrayList();
        myUnsafeArrayList.add("hello");
        myUnsafeArrayList.add(100);      
        myUnsafeArrayList.add("end");
        System.out.println("Before add: " + myUnsafeArrayList.get(0));
        
        myUnsafeArrayList.add(0, ((new ArrayList()).add("Hi")));
        System.out.println("After add: " + myUnsafeArrayList.get(0));
    }
}
```

Here is the output I get:

```
Before add: hello
After add: true
```

Comment: You're adding the result of evaluating `((new ArrayList()).add("Hi"))` to `myUnsafeArrayList`. What is that result? Did you mean to add `"Hi"` directly?

Comment: `((new ArrayList()).add("Hi"))` returns `true`

Comment: `ArrayList.add` has a boolean return type indicating whether the value was correctly added to the `ArrayList`. If you want to initialize an `ArrayList` with a single value, you can use `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Hi"))`, and add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```java
public class DataTypes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList myUnsafeArrayList =  new ArrayList();
        myUnsafeArrayList.add("hello");
        myUnsafeArrayList.add(100);      
        myUnsafeArrayList.add("end");
        System.out.println("Before add: " + myUnsafeArrayList.get(0));
        
        myUnsafeArrayList.add(0, Arrays.asList("Hi"));
        System.out.println("After add: " + myUnsafeArrayList.get(0));
    }
}
```

The reason being that with `myUnsafeArrayList.add(0, ((new ArrayList()).add("Hi")));` you are saying "add to index 0 of `myUnsafeArrayList` the result of `((new ArrayList()).add("Hi"))`". If you check the [reference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) the `add(E element)` returns a `boolean` and that is why you actually get `true` instead of `Hi`.

Comment: That's not what I need. I need an ArrayList as an element of an ArrayList.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please check it ;)

Comment: @nicomp That's not what you say in your question _I expect the String "Hi" to be added to the ArrayList at the 0th index._

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You're right. I will fix that!